# Master Boot Record Error

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

Recently my boot configuration was corrupted. Due to this, my system could not recognize C drive.

I tried to reformat the system thinking that I would be able to clean up the entire hard disk and create the partitions again. However, still when I start the installations of OS, the OS cannot recognize 50GB [the space that C drive had taken up] of my hard disk.

I am clueless on how to go ahead. Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Windows **Recovery Console** to fix your Master Boot Record. To do that, boot from Windows 7 installation disc, choose your language settings, and then click Next. Click "**Repair your computer**". On the **System Recovery Options** menu, choose **Command Prompt**. Now type **bootrec.exe** and press Enter. This will rebuild the boot configuration data and hopefully fix your problem. You can also run the command with switches to fix just the master boot record (**/fixmbr**), the boot sector (**/fixboot**), or rebuild the entire BCD (**/rebuildbcd**).